# Javascript - getElementById.innerHTML Problem

Tags: javascript

I want to create a simple formular which leads the user to 2 different pages (depending on what they choose). I'am using getElementById.innerHTML to differ the code within the site to create the two different `<form action="SENDTHEUSERHERE" method="POST">`-HTML-Elements.
Here's the code:

```
 if (blabla which works) 
  { 
    document.getElementById("insert").innerHTML = "<form action='insert.php' method='POST'>"; 
  }
 else if (blabla which works) 
  { 
    document.getElementById("service").innerHTML = "<form action='service.php' method='POST'>";  
  }

 // MORE BLABLA-CODE

  <span id='insert'></span>
  <span id='service'></span>

  // REST OF THE FORMULAR
```

When I'am sending this formular, it leads me simply to the same page it was sent from. I guess that means, that those .innerHTML-Elements aren't recognized. Have you any suggestions how I can solve this? Btw.. yes, I'am a Javascript Noob -_-

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can't you make the form a definite presence on the page and give it an id. Then use javascript to get it and change its action attribute?

Comment: There is not enough detail here to determine what's wrong. Post a complete example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the form action instead of using `innerHTML`...

```
if (conditionOne) {
    document.forms['formName'].action = 'insert.php';
} else if (conditionTwo) {
    document.forms['formName'].action = 'service.php';
} else {
    alert('Error!');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to post either your full HTML page + javascript code or a working example showing the problem. From the little you posted, it's impossible to tell what could be wrong.

But, that said, you're going about this problem in the wrong way. Instead of changing the innerHTML of some nodes, have one form with no action, and then in javascript do something like:

```
<form id="myForm">

var myForm = document.getElementById( "myForm" );
myForm.action = ( someConditionHere ) ? "insert.php" : "service.php";
```

Comment: That would more than 370 lines of code. I guess nobody want to read that. :)
I think the problems comes from the .innerHTML-thing

Answer (score 1):

If your example is what you need to do, you can just modify the action attribute of an existing form.

```
<form method='post' action='nowhere'>
<stuff>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
if (something) {
  document.forms[0].action = 'insert.php';
} else {
  //etc
}
</script>
```